# Are there templated math functions in cuda?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have been looking for templated math function in cuda and I can't seem to find one.  In normal c++ if I call `std::sqrt` it is templated and will execute a different version based on if the argument is a float or double.

I want something like this for CUDA device code.  My kernels have the real type passed as a template parameter and right now I have to choose between using `sqrtf` for float and `sqrt` for double.  I thought thrust might have this feature but it only does for complex numbers.

Comment: Generally speaking, CUDA is a subset of C++. The standard math functions in CUDA are overloaded based on argument type, so you can write `sqrt(float)` to compute a single-precision square root, or `sqrt(double)` to compute  a double-precision square root. I am reasonably sure this is documented in the CUDA documentation.

Comment: There is a [thrust](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html) library that implements some templated functions.

Comment: I've added a short answer summarizing the comments and delete answer so this gets an answer. I would appreciate it if the answer gets an upvote or is accepted so that this falls off the unanswered queue

Answer (score 1):

[Turning comments, a deleted answer, and some additional history into an answer to get this off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag, please edit and modify as you see fit]

**TLDR; Yes**

The original Open64 based toolchain had decent template support added during 2008-2009 (making things like Komrade and later Thrust possible), and the modern front end is really a proper subset of C++. Because template support and host C++ compilation has been baked into the toolchain since somewhere in CUDA 2 development cycle, the support code and math libraries have evolved in a fully template based overload system.

As a result, the standard math functions in CUDA are overloaded based on argument type, so you can write `sqrt(float)` to compute a single-precision square root, or `sqrt(double)` to compute a double-precision square root.

This is documented in the CUDA documentation [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH.html#group__CUDA__MATH).